# Android OpenStreetMap shows marker instead of map

Tags: android, maps, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am developing an Android application. I need to locate the user. So I want to use Google OpenStreetMap.  I want to integrate the open street view to my application, but when the application starts, the map is not loaded. Instead  I get only a marker. Here is my code:

```
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.MyLocationOverlay;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MyItemizedOverlay myItemizedOverlay = null;
    MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        Drawable marker = getResources().getDrawable(
                android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
        int markerWidth = marker.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int markerHeight = marker.getIntrinsicHeight();
        marker.setBounds(0, markerHeight, markerWidth, 0);

        ResourceProxy resourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(
                getApplicationContext());

        myItemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(marker, resourceProxy);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myItemizedOverlay);

        GeoPoint myPoint1 = new GeoPoint(0 * 1000000, 0 * 1000000);
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(myPoint1, "myPoint1", "myPoint1");
        GeoPoint myPoint2 = new GeoPoint(50 * 1000000, 50 * 1000000);
        myItemizedOverlay.addItem(myPoint2, "myPoint2", "myPoint2");

        myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
        mapView.getOverlays(`enter code here`).add(myLocationOverlay);
        myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();    
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set a tile source. Please call `setTileSource()` on your `MapView` object appropriately.

And please don't mix up terms, there is no "google open street maps". The project is called OpenStreetMap (without a *s* at the end) and Google is not involved at all.

Comment: thank you fro your help and your advice  , can you tell me how can I calculate the distance between two places please ?

Comment: Please ask a new question about this issue. And accept my answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: I can't ask new question I must wait 3 days so please help me how to claclate the distance ?

Comment: Take a look at `osmbonuspack`. It builds up on top of osmdroid and adds various features, including routing.

Comment: thank you can I have some indication i don't found a good tutorial thank tou